# PHP new line \n and \r\n not working

Tags: php, line, newline, break

```
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($result) ;
  for ($j=0 ; $j < 3 ; $j++) {
  for ($i=0 ; $i < 3 ; $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ;
    echo '<a href="image2.php?id='.$row['ID'].'">'."<img src='".$row['Image']."' />".'</a>' ;

  }
   echo "\r\n";
  }
```

The code displays three groups of three images. My understanding was that \r\n and \n (double quotes) should create a new line. However it is just inserting a space between the images. Is the way am callign \r\n wrong or is it am using the wrong code to isneert a new line (line break)

Examples (# = one image):

Without echo \r\n: #########
With echo \r\n: ### ### ###

Comment: If you make html page you should use `<br>` tag, if it's console application use `PHP_EOL`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `echo "\r\n";` is outside the loop. Move it inside the loop.

Also, if you want the line breaks to be visible in the browser, you should print a `<br />` too.

```
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($result) ;
  for ($j=0 ; $j < 3 ; $j++) {
  for ($i=0 ; $i < 3 ; $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ;
    echo '<a href="image2.php?id='.$row['ID'].'">'."<img src='".$row['Image']."' />".'</a>' ;
  }
    echo "<br />\n";    
  }
```

Comment: Just tried this method and it works. Dont know if you mis-read my question but the current postions is correct. Thanks for the help

Comment: Just fixed the code and moved the `echo` back to the original position.

Answer (score 13):

Whitespace [is not displayed verbatim](http://www.maproom.co.uk/invis1.htm) when it's part of HTML text. `\r` and `\n` are not universal constants; they are just characters, and it's up to whatever program consumes them to decide what to do with them.

You should use [`<br>`](http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/br/) instead.

Comment: It should be `<br />`, and not `<br>`, to be valid xml. since `br` must be a self closing tag.

Comment: in addition: check out the source (`ctrl+u` in most browsers), the newlines are visible there

Comment: @twall: Do you actually know *why* it has to be valid XML? Answer: it actually does not, unless you use an XML content type (which noone uses); people who *do* have fixed their tags already because user agents would not display the page at all otherwise. `<br>` is valid HTML4 and valid HTML5.

Comment: @Jon ... well since the OP had closed their `<img  />` tag it only makes sense to assume that they might want to close their `<br />` tag as well. I tend to close everything - I find it easier to remember to do that than try and remember what the exceptions are.

Comment: @CD001: I do that too (picked up the habit back when I didn't know better), but my point is that it offers absolutely nothing so we could do ourselves a favor and retrain to type two less characters per such tag.

Comment: @Jon - lol, very true - not to mention saving all the `</p>` as IIRC they're optional as well :)

Answer (score 5):

You need:

```
echo '<br />';
```

instead of:

```
echo "\r\n";
```

Comment: Answer is correct but some clarification for other people would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider setting a proper header
Exmaple:

```
$data = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
];
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
foreach($data as $row){
    echo implode(',', $row) . "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to a problem of "\r\n" not rendering new lines in the browser if you can't use <br>.